# The Chinese English parallel corpus from Wikidata?

Tags: wikidata, dbpedia, china

I have these two corpora: 1) [wikidata alias](https://databus.dbpedia.org/dbpedia/wikidata/alias/); 2) [wikidata labels](https://databus.dbpedia.org/dbpedia/wikidata/labels/).

What confused me is that [数学常数](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%A6%E5%B8%B8%E6%95%B0) and [Mathematical constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_constant)'s QIDs are respectively Q866140 and Q186509, even though they are linked to each other by switching languages. The traditional Chinese version [數學常數](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hant/%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%A6%E5%B8%B8%E6%95%B0)'s QID is the same as [Mathematical constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_constant)'s, and the former is also linked with the latter by the language setting. I filtered in only alias and labels with language codes "en" and "zh".

Are there something wrong? Or how to download interlanguage links data? [This interlanguage links dataset](https://databus.dbpedia.org/dbpedia/generic/interlanguage-links/) is too small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to note that you are linking to *dbpedia's version of Wikidata*, as noted in the other question, and they might have done things a little differently when processing it. I can't really answer from the dbpedia side of things, so this is a Wikidata-oriented answer...

The Wikipedia pages you mention link to the same item, https://wikidata.org/wiki/Q186509 - the other item links to a related set of WP pages, in English "Mathematical constants by continued fraction representation". However, this item has had its Chinese label truncated (it lost the brackets in 数学常数 (以连分数表示排列)) and so it shows up on Wikidata with the same Chinese label as the first.

If you are simply matching on labels or aliases, then the key thing to know is that Wikidata's labels and aliases are **not unique**. There might be a hundred items with an identical "John Smith" label in English and fifty more with that alias. In general, Wikidata does not keep the disambiguation notes in brackets from Wikipedia page titles, which is probably why the Chinese one here lost the bracketed section, but there can be many other differences.

You can get a copy of the full set of the interlanguage links from the Wikidata dumps at https://dumps.wikimedia.org/ - you will want the wikidatawiki dump and the wb-items-per-site file ("For each Wikidata item, this contains rows with the corresponding page name on a given wiki project."). Documentation for the file is [at mediawiki.org](https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Schema/wb_items_per_site/en) and more general documentation on the dumps is [available on Wikidata](https://m.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Database_download).

Comment: BTW, how can I find the doc of that dataset? And what is this? dumps.wikimedia.org/wikidatawiki/entities

Comment: @LernerZhang I've added some documentation links